# Remove composer

Tags: composer-php, uninstallation

I installed composer while trying to install CakePHP, but the installation was not successful and I want to uninstall composer.
I am not finding any way to do this.

For the installation I used the command:

```
curl -s https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
```

I am working in Linux.

Comment: What do you mean by "but the installation was not successful"? Would you care for fixing installation?

Comment: @TomasVotruba I mean that some components were not installed properly. I would care for fixing it - if I could. But I've struggled with fixing it for a while now so I thought I would just try to install it all over.

Answer (score 114, accepted):

During the installation you got a message 
`Composer successfully installed to: ...` this indicates where Composer was installed. But you might also search for the file `composer.phar` on your system.

Then simply:

1. Delete the file `composer.phar`.
2. Delete the Cache Folder:

   - Linux: `/home/<user>/.composer`
   - Windows: `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\Composer`

That's it.

Comment: Where is the composer file?

Comment: just add little extra information that I didn't find the `.composer` and was unable to reinstall it again. I just did it by deleting the `composer` folder in `C:\Users\myusername\AppData\Roaming` and it worked.

Comment: @BasheerAhmed This question was related to installation on linux machine and it seems like you are using windows.

Comment: @BasheerAhmed Good point, Ahmed! I've updated my answer and included that. Thank you.

Comment: just a reminder. If you installed composer from the root account, you have to delete the files from that same account, otherwise you will get the error "permission denied".

Comment: The composer cache folder is sometimes at `/home/<user>/.config/composer`

Comment: Remember that composer can also be install with Homebrew as well. Make sure that it's removed there by running `brew unlink composer` followed by `brew remove composer`. And to make sure that you find all Composer-installations, then go to your root (`cd /`) and run this command: `find ./* -name 'composer.phar'` and this `find ./* -name 'composer'. That should tell you of all the locations where the Composer-installation can be installed.

Comment: Just use the uninstaller located at C:\ProgramData\Composer\bin

Comment: I can't find composer.phar in debian even after updatedb and locate composer.phar

Comment: if someone with macOS searching for it , then you can fire `$ which composer` in terminal and you will get composer's location

Comment: I can't find the.composer.phar on windows. I use the windows compser version! How can I to uninstall the composer?

Comment: To be really complete in Windows you may also have to remove it from your PATH

Comment: not make sense, it is a big `apt` package as Pažout answer, or really only one file as  here? Please explain...

Comment: Its just one file. Plus some additional cache folders.. The OP fetches this file using Curl. -- But its also possible that someone wrapped this file into an AptPackage for (easier) installation on linux/debian distros.

Answer (score 57):

**Uninstall composer**

To remove just composer package itself from Ubuntu 16.04 (Xenial Xerus) execute on terminal:

```
sudo apt-get remove composer
```

**Uninstall composer and it's dependent packages**

To remove the composer package and any other dependant package which are no longer needed from Ubuntu Xenial.

```
sudo apt-get remove --auto-remove composer
```

**Purging composer**

If you also want to delete configuration and/or data files of composer from Ubuntu Xenial then this will work:

```
sudo apt-get purge composer
```

To delete configuration and/or data files of composer and it's dependencies from Ubuntu Xenial then execute:

```
sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove composer
```

https://www.howtoinstall.co/en/ubuntu/xenial/composer?action=remove

Comment: not make sense, it is [one file as jens's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30399584/287948) or an `apt` package? Please explain...

Answer (score 40):

#### Additional information about removing/uninstalling composer

Answers above did not help me, but what did help me is removing:

1. `~/.cache/composer`
2. `~/.local/share/composer`
3. `~/.config/composer`
4. `~/.composer`

Actual directories can be obtained by the composer command:

```
$ echo home cache-dir data-dir | xargs -n1 composer config --global
~/.config/composer
~/.cache/composer
~/.local/share/composer
```

Comment: In my case removing the installation file was enough. but in many other scenarios you may need to remove configuration files, cache etc. Generally speaking it is a good idea to remove every file installed, whether you want to reinstall or uninstall a package / program. Thumbs up for the answer.

Comment: on debian I don't have those files, and yet the problem persists

Answer (score 19):

If you install the composer as global on Ubuntu, you just need to find the composer location.

Use command

```
type composer
```

or

```
where composer
```

For Mac users, use command:

```
which composer
```

and then just remove the folder using `rm` command.

Comment: which composer for macos.

Comment: Thanks, helped my day.

Comment: For mac users - `which composer` will be used. I'll add it to the answer.

Answer (score 11):

Find the Location of the Composer by typing this command

```
whereis composer
```

Then You will get the output like this

```
composer: /usr/local/bin/composer
```

Then:

```
cd /usr/local/bin/
```

And remove composer by this command

```
sudo rm -r composer
```

Answer (score 10):

Is this the way you installed it?

```
curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | sudo php
sudo mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer
export PATH="$HOME/.composer/vendor/bin:$PATH"
```

If you have installed by this way simply delete `composer.phar` from where you put it.

In this case path will be:

```
/usr/local/bin/composer
```

Run this command:

```
sudo rm /usr/local/bin/composer/composer.phar
```

Note: There is no need to delete the exported path.