# 'Zsh: command not found: valet' - unable to install Valet

Tags: homebrew, laravel-valet

I just tried installing `valet` for a very long time, - and I couldn't find [any](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37085102/laravel-valet-install-not-found) [help](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/problems-with-valet-installation?page=1) anywhere. No matter what I tried, then it kept saying:

```
Zsh: command not found: valet
```

I'm running [Zshell](http://ohmyz.sh/) (instead of Bash) and OSX. I've had Brew installed for quite a while.

I'll answer this myself, - so hopefully people in the same situation can find this in the future.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Everywhere it says to 'Check that your path is right'. And yup - if you haven't done that, then you should start there. The easiest way is to go to your terminal and write:

```
echo $PATH
```

... And then you should see `~/.composer/vendor/bin` in between two colons in there. If that isn't there, then you should go to your `~/.bashrc`-file (or `~/.zshrc`-file) and add this line:

```
export $PATH=~/.composer/vendor/bin:$PATH
```

And then it may be fixed.

My problem had deeper roots, though. Even though my path was right, then I still got the error:

```
Zsh: command not found: valet
```

And if I wrote: `which valet` - then it (obviously) just responded with `valet not found`.

**Removal of `Composer`**

What fixed it was to remove all my `composer`-installations. Composer can be located in several different locations (and installed by brew). So in order to remove it, then do this (inspired by [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30396451/remove-composer), but it lacks a couple of steps):

- Remove your `composer`- or -`composer.phar`-file. You can find them by running `which composer` and/or `which composer.phar`.
- Remove your `.composer`-folder (usually located here: `~/.composer`).
- Then make sure that there isn't an installation done with Homebrew (this was what I think made the collision for me). You do it by running `brew unlink composer` followed by `brew remove composer`.
- Then, - if you want to be 100% sure that it's all gone, then go to your root (`cd /`) and run this command: `find ./* -name 'composer.phar'` and this `find ./* -name 'composer'`. That should tell you of all the locations where the Composer-installation can be installed.

When all that's removed, then you should be rid of Composer (entirely).
... Then install it again, - and see if you can get `valet` to work (it did for me).

Answer (score 8):

The solution was adding composer bin to the path. You can use the following commands

From the terminal

1. `export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.composer/vendor/bin"`
2. `echo 'export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.composer/vendor/bin"' >> ~/.bash_profile`
3. `source ~/.bash_profile`
4. `valet install`

Comment: If you're looking to be as lazy as possible, this worked when I used brew to install composer. 

Answer (score 5):

I had a very similar problem under Zsh, but my solution was easier. Rather than adding `~/.composer/vendor/bin` to my `$PATH`, I needed to use the full directory name; i.e., `/Users/[your-user-name]/.composer/vendor/bin`.

Answer (score 2):

I tried all above, but always

```
zsh: command not found: valet
```

My solution was to have the path like this:

```
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.composer/vendor/bin"
```

(with a $HOME instead of ~)

Answer (score 0):

Issue Ubuntu: no command valet

Valet on Ubuntu:

> sudo apt install libnss3-tools jq xsel
>
> composer global require cpriego/valet-linux
>
> .composer/vendor/cpriego/valet-linux/valet install

Now command valet should work, but if still not:

> sudo cp .composer/vendor/cpriego/valet-linux/valet /usr/local/bin/